# C# Fallback font for winform application

Tags: c#-4.0, fonts

I develop a application for Korean, cause in my apllication sometimes appear Korean character. But my apllication using font "Verdana", so font "Verdana" not support Korean character, and Window system auto change to font "Gulim", but i don't want so Korean character by this font, I want show Kerean character by font "Malgun Gothic".

In WPF can set [fallback font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily(v=vs.110).aspx) for application, how to do that in winform application.

How can set fallback font as wpf:

```
    FontFamily f = new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS, Verdana");
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: Font fallback for TrueType fonts is [done by Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/396160/how-to-change-configure-font-fallback).